# SQL Server 2005 replication - indicate data is replicated

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, database-replication

I am using SQL Server 2005 replication to replicate data from one table on a server to the a table on a remote server. This is happening in real time. i.e whenever the data is changed at the publisher, it is then replicated to the subscribers.

From the publisher's server I need to know what data has been replicated to the subscriber.  Is there a way to figure this out using SQL?

thanks

Comment: MakkyNZ: did you get the answer you were looking for?  If so, could you please accept it?  If not, could you clarify what you are still looking for?

Answer (score 0):

select publ.pk_col
FROM
 pubdb.dbo.tbl publ
 JOIN linked_server_subscriber.pubdb.dbo.tbl subs
  ON publ.pk_col = subs.pk_col